# Setting Private Memory Limit for application pool in IIS 7 increased page faults before crossing the limit

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, memory, iis-7

I have set Private Memory limit of 200mb in IIS 7 for an application pool. The Private Working Set memory(Task Manager) for the application is always below 125mb but the number of page faults have increased a lot and application cache is getting cleared frequently after setting the limit.

I haven't set any limit on Virtual Memory. Can someone suggest why the cache is getting cleared even when the Private memory used is below the allocated memory?

Comment: are those soft faults or hard faults?

Comment: it is task manager's page fault counter. Please correct me If I am wrong, the I/O reads for the process are very low(almost negligible) compared to Page faults counter, so most of them are soft faults. Is there a better way to find soft faults and hard faults for an IIS application process. Using counters like Memory\ Page Faults /sec, Memory\Transition Faults/sec we can get data corresponding to entire server but cannot be limited to single application process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at the Working Set (Memory) column in Task Manager, you are looking at the Memory (Private Working Set) column, which is smaller.

Comment: The Working Set Memory is fluctuating between 150mb and 170mb which is  below the memory limit I have set.